# How to aggregate only non duplicates values using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe below:

```
    ID  COL1    COL2
0   id001   val1    xxxxx
1   id001   val1    yyyyy
2   id002   val2    yyyyy
3   id003   val3    zzzzz
4   id003   val4    zzzzz
```

And this is the expected output:

```
ID  COL1    COL2
0   id001   val1    xxxxx|yyyyy
1   id002   val2    yyyyy
2   id003   val3|val4   zzzzz
```

I made the code below but unfortunately `val1` (first row) and `zzzzz` (last row) are repeated.

```
df_gr = df[['COL1', 'COL2']].astype(str).groupby(df['ID']).agg('|'.join).reset_index()

    ID  COL1    COL2
0   id001   val1|val1   xxxxx|yyyyy
1   id002   val2    yyyyy
2   id003   val3|val4   zzzzz|zzzzz
```

Do you know how to fix this, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I needed to convert an array to a list with string elements before applying `join`:

```
df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'COL1': 'unique', 'COL2':'unique'}).applymap(lambda x: '|'.join(map(str, x))).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df[['COL1', 'COL2']].astype(str).groupby(['ID','COL1']).agg('|'.join).reset_index()
```

This will limit you groupby and formulate a single series, after that you just need to append the series into your df

Comment: Hi, I run it and I got only two columns. Could you re-check my expected output, please ?

Comment: If you want your entire dataset as return check edit

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns `KeyError: 'ID'`